# Handshaking not happening between master and slave in jenkins

Tags: windows, hudson, jenkins, ubuntu-12.04, jenkins-plugins

How to solve this error? Error occurred since I make master ip to public and assign DNS.

```
Jul 27, 2012 12:44:17 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Hudson agent is running in headless mode.
Jul 27, 2012 12:44:17 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://10.10.1.162:8080/jenkins/, http://dem
Jul 27, 2012 12:44:38 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to demo.sigmainfo.in:8050
Jul 27, 2012 12:44:38 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Jul 27, 2012 12:44:58 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: The server rejected the connection:
java.lang.Exception: The server rejected the connection:
  at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:258)
  at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:233)
```

I have seen so many thread regarding this, but didn't get any answer properly.

I connected using headless slave agent and put HOST:PORT in advanced setting of configuration of slave. Master is linux and slave is windows 7.

Comment: What version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: 1.144 i am using..it was working earlier..but when i changed the port of master machine to open.. and assign domain name..After that i am getting this error...

Comment: Jenkins is currently at version 1.475, so it seems you are using a very old version. Is there any reason for that? Also, can you post the exact command you gave it for the headless agent?

Comment: 1.447.2 i am using..sorry for the correction..because conditional plugin(multiple) is not working..command i have used is same which is displayed before connecting slave to master..java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://10.10.1.50:8050/jenkins/computer/Openbravo-slave/slave-agent.jnlp ; it is working without public ip ,dns and port number..Worked with launch also..problem arise when i connect to dns..with new port..

Comment: Since you are having problems with the public IP & DNS, can you make sure that routing for the public IP and DNS is allowed on your network. Just to be sure this is not a firewall issue. Are you on a corporate network? In that case, your corporate firewall may be blocking certain ports on all IP addresses.

Comment: Also, can you check if you can ping that public IP address, and also ping using the DNS name?

Comment: i am not able to ping using dns.ip is working..Requested timed out is showing..i have given fixed portno.for jnlp slave and add inbound and outbound rule to enable all type of connections and protocol..DNS Name you pointed out is not working..In firewall blockinbound and unblock outbound is showing, when checking status..i am on a corporate network..Sonic firewall they are using..Private and public network firewall is in on state..home networks it is in off state..When i checked status, it's showing off..

Comment: "problem arise when i connect to dns..with new port" can you try using the public IP address then? Your DNS server is not resolving your hostname to the public IP address; may be you need to add it manually?

Comment: Problem is solved..thanks for you support..i have created one inbound and outbound rule for tcp port number to allow packet sending..Firewall was blocking the portnumbers..i gave fixed port number for slave also..Thank you so much..

Comment: No problem. I'll place my answer in the answer section of the question, in case it helps anyone else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Comments:

**=================================**

Since you are having problems with the public IP & DNS, can you make sure that routing for the public IP and DNS is allowed on your network. Just to be sure this is not a firewall issue. Are you on a corporate network? In that case, your corporate firewall may be blocking certain ports on all IP addresses.